# check if a bytes-array is a hex-literal

Tags: python, string, decoding

From an API I receive following types of bytes-array:

```
b'2021:09:30 08:28:24'

b'\x01\x02\x03\x00'
```

I know how to get the values for them, like for the first one with `value.decode()` and for the second one with `''.join([str(c) for c in value])`

the problem is, I need to do this dynamically. I don't know what the second one is called (is it a hex-literal?), but I can't even check for `value.decode().startswith('\x')`, it gives me a

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape

which makes sense, because of the escape sequence.

so, I need something that checks, if the value is from format `\x...` or a simple string I can just use with `decode()`.

Comment: … anyway, the API should *tell* you how to decode the values it sends you. Either inside the message, or inside the documentation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph damn.. mixed second/first... I corrected it. no, I want the actual date for the date-one:)

Comment: The two byte values are not inherently different, it is just just the implementation of byte to present certain bytes (the ones in ASCII character strings) as ascii characters and others as hex codes. You can always `try` to decode them and catech the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of try/except with isprintable():

```
def bytes_to_string(data):
    try:
        rv = data.decode()
        return rv if rv.isprintable() else data.hex()
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return data.hex()

print(bytes_to_string(b'\x01\x02\x03\x00'))    # Will decode but to unprintable string
print(bytes_to_string(b'2021:09:30 08:28:24')) # Will decode to printable string
print(bytes_to_string(b'Z\xfcrich'))           # Will throw an exception on decode
```

Comment: haha yeah, got that exception on testing with some curious data.. perfect..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isprintable` to approximate a check for escape sequences inside a string literal:

```
str_val = value.decode()
if not str_val.isprintable():
    str_val = ''.join([str(c) for c in value])
```

However, as noted in my comment, this seems like an unnecessary hack, and unreliable at that. The fundamental issue is that there is no hard boundary for telling different byte buffers apart, only heuristics (this is a fundamental theorem of communication theory; there is no way around it!). The API that sends the data should therefore *tell* you how to interpret the data.

Comment: yes, this works :) - yeah, the values are coming from exif-tags, so no documentation... but it's a nice hack I can use for now

Comment: This will not work, if the bytes happen to not be unicode.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Actually you should accept treuss’ answer, theirs is better than mine. My code will fail if the byte string contains invalid UTF-8 data.